# Is it possible to contrain inferred generics in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Take the following example:

```js
type A<Keys extends string, Prefix extends string> = 
  {[K in Keys]: `${Prefix}-${K}`}

function noGood<K extends string, Prefix extends string>(
  obj: A<K, Prefix>, prefix: Prefix
) {
// ...
}

const test: A<'one' | 'two', 'prefix'> = {"one": 'prefix-one', "two": 'prefix-two'}

noGood(test, 'desired to only be "prefix", but can be any string...')
```

You can see that the generic types of noGood are inferred from the first param (`obj`). Then, when you provide a string to the second param (`prefix`)

Obviously you could type out your call to `noGood` and it would disallow that random string for the second parameter, but ideally you wouldn't have to.

Edit:
The question was not clear.

To clarify, the problem is that when you infer the arguments to `noGood`, the `Prefix` inferrence does not work as desired (but not necessarily unexpected) since it would be ideal to have the `Prefix` constrained to the generic `Prefix` of `obj` (the first argument).

In this example, `Prefix` (generic) is literally `'prefix'` and it would be desired to only allow that for the `noGood` second argument that is inferred. However, when you call `noGood(obj, 'diff-prefix')` the `Prefix` generic becomes `'prefix' | 'diff-prefix'` and ideally it would be constrained to the inferred type from `obj` rather than the inferred type from the union of the first and the second argument.

Hope that clears things up. Can definitely see how it was unclear.

Comment: I don't get it; does `desired to only be "one" or "two", but...` mean you want to support `noGood(test, "one")`?  If so, then why is it typed `Prefix` instead of `K` [like this](https://tsplay.dev/mqvVqW)?  If not, then why does that string say that?  Is there a typo or something here? I'm confused; help!

Comment: @jcalz, sorry that is my fault. It should be "prefix-one" or "prefix-two", not just "one" or "two".

Comment: Then why are you typing it `Prefix` instead of `\`${Prefix}-${K}\`` [like this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ8O6N)?  Can you articulate what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

@HelloWorld per your comment on my other answer, if you want the parameter `prefix` to only be a value at one of the keys of the object, it is still relatively easy with some tweaks:

```
const foo = {"one": 'prefix-one' as const, "two": 'prefix-two' as const}

function noGood<O extends {}>(
  obj: O, prefix: O[keyof O]
) {
// ...
}

noGood(foo, 'prefix-one'); // sure ok
noGood(foo, 'crabapple'); // error!
```

Note the use of `as const` when defining the values inside of `foo`. This is important because it tells TypeScript that those are values will not change and can be treated as a constant, explicit type and not just any old `string`. Otherwise, `noGood(foo, 'crabapple')` would not give an error because TypeScript normally would infer the values at each key of `foo` as a `string` and not `"prefix-one" | "prefix-two"`.

If this still doesn't meet your use case, please update your question with more specific details and requirements.

Comment: Again, sorry i asked the question poorly and gave the wrong example (twice...). I have made a bigger edit and that should have made everything clear.

It should only be "prefix" and not the keys of the object.

Comment: @HelloWorld what you are trying to do isn't really possible using only TypeScript inferred types. You can easily do it by explicitly passing types into the generic of `noGood()` without even making changes to your example code: `noGood<keyof typeof test, 'prefix'>(test, 'desired to only be "prefix", but can be any string...'); // will now error`. But it kind of defeats the purpose, because you have to explicitly pass `"prefix"` to the generic, and if you're already doing that you're just repeating yourself.

Comment: thanks @jered. yeah was hoping to there was some other constraint that might implicitly infer the type. I haven't used the `infer` type and wasn't sure if that would do the trick in some way I wasn't able to ascertain from the examples of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial at a basic level if you don't care too much about constraining the object parameter of "`noGood()`". Use generics to enforce that the parameter `prefix` is a key of the object parameter `obj` (the word "prefix" seems like a misnomer here since you seem to only care about the keys of `obj` but I digress):

```
function noGood<O extends{}>(
  obj: O, prefix: keyof O
) {
// ...
}
```

There is not really a way that I know of to extract the type information for "`Prefix`" from your type `A` because that generic type information is not retained by the object after you instantiate it -- there is just no way to enforce that the object passed in as `obj` is definitely an instance of your type `A`.

Comment: sorry I typed it wrong above. It should be "prefix-one" or "prefix-two", the combination of the prefix and the key, not just the key. For sure a trivial solution as you said otherwise.